# Removing unwanted files/folders from SVN sync log

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I am using eclipse indigo for a maven based java project, client is using SVN for saving code to a central location. i also installed the eclipse SVN plugin to commit the code to SVN, but the issue is when i sync the project with repository eclipse shows  me changes i made in the code but along with that it also shows me unwanted changes of build/target etc folder as well that makes the log too long and some times it became difficult for me to find the files. That is why my question is can we exclude some files/folders from the log. See the screenshot here i like to exclude target folder,

[image]

**Note:** There is an option of "Remove from view" i-e when i right click on any file/folder it gives me this option but i want a permanent setting. is this possible using some configuration etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the `svn:ignore` property?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html

Answer (score 4):

Right click the entity and select `Team` -> `Add to SVN:ignore`.